# Why a select query is running slower in Oracle than sql server

Tags: oracle, query-optimization, odp.net

I am reading data from Oracle database by using ODP.Net with the follwing code

```
    OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand( SELECT ID,RECORD(XMLType) FROM tbl_Name, con);
            con.Open();
        OracleDataReader _dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (_dataReader.Read())
                {
     string rowId = _dataReader[0].ToString();
                 string xmlString = _dataReader[1].ToString();
    adding this data into Queue for further processing
    }
```

It working fine but in a minute it's reading only 10000 record. If I use SqlServer database  it's reading 500000 record in minute having table with same schema.

Please help me if I am missing something to read data faster using ODP.NET

Thank you.

**

- ANSWER:

**

I have tried with GetClobVal() and GetString Val() functions, now it is working fine.

select t.RECID, t.XMLRECORD.GetClobVal() from  tableName  t"

select x.RECID,x.XMLRECORD.getStringVal() from  tableName  x"

If we use these queries with oracle command it will run fast, but not as fast as sql server query.

Comment: I doubt very much that the .Net code has much to do with database performance.  To have any hope of answering your question we'd have to see the schemas as they exist in both SQL Server and Oracle, including such things as indexes, triggers, constraints, and we'd need the record counts which exist in both databases, and have some assurance that the data in both systems is identical.  A dump of the execution plan of your query in both systems would also be needed to offer any opinions.